# Index-match function in excel

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

This is a sample of a large data set. I am trying to find value for E014, so I have to move four columns right and two rows down. This is not hard using offset-match formula. However, offset first uses row and then column argument. I need to move 2 rows down, but after doing this formula looks at third row and it is not possible to match based on first row values. Would anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can't you use twice MATCH and locate row number of `1.1.01`? Is this row dynamic or is it always in same position? IS the value always 2 rows below row containing `E014`? Is the header row always in the same place?

Answer (score 0):

Use address function for this:

`=ADDRESS(MAX(($B$2:$F$4=$C$9)*ROW($B$2:$F$4)),MAX(($B$2:$F$4=$C$9)*COLUMN($B$2:$F$4)),4)`

Confirm this array-formula with `ctrl + shift + enter`

I used `$B$2:$F$4` for the range of your data. Change it to the range you have.
I used `$C$9` for the lookup value you could replace it for `"E014"` if you prefer, or change it to a different cell where you like to type the value to search for.

Please note this only works properly if the value is found once in you data.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it hasn't worked. The formula indicates an error for the second MAX argument (MAX(($B$2:$F$4=$C$9).

Comment: Did you enter as array, like mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I tried, however the error doesn't allow for the array to work.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Po39w8RJYRhek8Xp9

Did you change the range to fit the actual range you're using?